# Using .at results in a ValueError or TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a bit new to pandas, after using the csv library for quite a while. In the code below I'm essentially trying to get the value in the Barcode column of the row that has the same SKU number that is in itemsku. It works until it gets to the assigning of the barcode variable. It states the following error `ValueError: At based indexing on an integer index can only have integer indexers` as I said I am new to pandas so have probably done an absolute rookie mistake any help would be great

```
def getBarcode(itemsku, newdbpath):
    df = pd.read_csv(newdbpath)
    row = df.loc[df['SKU'] == itemsku]
    rowIndex = row.index
    barcode = df.at[rowIndex, 'Barcode']
    return barcode
```

Here's the dataFrame:

```
,SKU,PartCode,Brand,Model,Option,StockLevel,ActualStockLevel,ParentCategory,Category,FullDescription,ImageURLs,ProductWeightGrams,Currency,RetailPriceExTax,Quantity1,Price1,Barcode
0,1234,1234,BrandEx,ModEx,,Yes,10,Model,,<p> Brilliant product for the home </p>,www.exampleurl.com,10,USD,20,7,15,503764857907
1,14442234,14442234,ExBrand,ExMod,,No,9,Model,,<p> example desc </p>,www.exampleweb.com,20,USD,30,5,20,503725193745
```

- Depending on the version of pandas, the error may differ.
- The posted error is:

```py
ValueError: At based indexing on an integer index can only have integer indexers
```

- pandas 1.2.1 error is different

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-41d012c979fd> in <module>
----> 1 getBarcode(1234, 'test.csv')

<ipython-input-57-a8fca6fde129> in getBarcode(itemsku, newdbpath)
      3     row = df.loc[df['SKU'] == itemsku]
      4     rowIndex = row.index  # you must extract a single value, at[...] will not accept a list or index
----> 5     barcode = df.at[rowIndex, 'Barcode']
      6     return barcode

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2154             return self.obj.loc[key]
   2155 
-> 2156         return super().__getitem__(key)
   2157 
   2158     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2101 
   2102         key = self._convert_key(key)
-> 2103         return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
   2104 
   2105     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _get_value(self, index, col, takeable)
   3131 
   3132         try:
-> 3133             loc = engine.get_loc(index)
   3134             return series._values[loc]
   3135         except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: 'Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')' is an invalid key
```

Answer (score 0):

- The OP indicates a `ValueError`, but in pandas 1.2.1, `barcode = df.at[rowIndex, 'Barcode']` results in `TypeError: 'Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')' is an invalid key`
- [`.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) accepts a single value, not a `list` or `indexer`, therefore you must extract the one index value that corresponds to `itemsku`.
- Using `.at` also assumes `row` only returns a single row, which means `SKU` is unique in the dataframe.
- Change `rowIndex = row.index` to `rowIndex = row.index[0]`

  - With the example data and `itemsku` as `1234`, `row.index` returns `Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')`, but `row.index[0]` returns `0`.

```py
def getBarcode(itemsku, newdbpath):
    df = pd.read_csv(newdbpath)
    row = df.loc[df['SKU'] == itemsku]
    rowIndex = row.index[0]  # you must extract a single value, at[...] will not accept a list or index
    barcode = df.at[rowIndex, 'Barcode']
    return barcode
```

- If `SKU` is not unique, and `row` will be more than one value, then `.loc` should be used instead of `.at`.

```py
def getBarcode(itemsku, newdbpath):
    df = pd.read_csv(newdbpath, index_col=0)
    row = df.loc[df['SKU'] == itemsku]
    rowIndex = row.index
    barcode = df.loc[rowIndex, 'Barcode']  # use .loc instead of .at if rowIndex is more than one value
    return barcode
```